# RethinkDB: how can I query nested arrays?

Tags: nested, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

I have a `person` object in RethinkDB that looks like this:

```
{
  "email": "user@domain.com", 
  "orders": {, 
    "id": 1,
    "additionalInvoices": [
      {
        "description": "Bananas", 
        "stripeChargeId": "ch_333"
      }, 
      {
        "description": "Apples", 
        "stripeChargeId": "ch_444"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Except no results are returned. Am I allowed to nest `contains()` functions? **What's the best way to get the results I want?**

**Edit:** I've also tried [`pluck()`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/pluck/) and describing the data structure, per this example of [using nested datastructures in the RethinkDB docs](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/nested-fields/javascript/) - I thought this works, but it gives an **empty object matching the query as the only result**:

```
rethink.db(DATABASE).table(TABLE).pluck(
  {orders: [{additionalInvoices: [{'stripeChargeId': chargeID}]}]}
).run(dbConnection, function(err, results) {
  if ( err ) {
    cb(err)
    return;
  }
  toOne(results, cb)
})
```

Comment: Can you fix your sample data? `"orders": [ id: 1, {` isn't valid JSON

Comment: @AtnNn Good spot! Fixed.